# Moodle, how to update $USER content after updating user role through data base

Tags: moodle

A user logs in to the server, current role of the user in a course context is editing teacher. I want to change the role to student, and test if attempt capability exists or not for the user in course context?

To change the role of user to student for a given context, I manually update the role_assignment table's role column from editing teacher role to student. Changes done directly show no effect unless the user logs out and logs in again.

To test the capability of the user I use $USER global variable.

Even after manually changing the role of the user to student $USER is not updated: $USER shows the changes only after user logs out and logs in again.

I think issue is related to browser cache, session.
How can I update $USER directly as soon as I change role?

Code used to change role of user:

```
$index = $context->depth-1;
$array = explode("/",$context->path);
$context_id = $array[$index];

// get logged in user id
$userId = $USER->id;

$user = $DB->get_record('role_assignments', array('contextid'=>$array[$index], 'userid'=> $userId));

$user->roleid = 5;
$roles = get_user_roles($context, $userId);
$user->timemodified = time();
$DB->update_record('role_assignments', $user, $bulk=false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code you want looks something a bit more like this:

```
$coursecontext = $context->get_course_context();
$teacherroleid = $DB->get_field('role', 'id', ['shortname' => 'editingteacher']);
$studentroleid = $DB->get_field('role', 'id', ['shortname' => 'student']);
role_assign($studentroleid, $USER->id, $coursecontext->id);
role_unassign($teacherroleid, $USER->id, $coursecontext->id);
```

I wasn't quite sure what you were trying to do by exploding the context path, so I assumed you were trying to get the course context (which I've done above). If you just wanted the id of the current context, then $context->id would have done.

It's not a good idea to hard code roleids, 5 is the student role in most clean installs, but looking it up is more reliable.

Using the proper Moodle functions to assign/unassign roles is much more reliable than manually messing around with database entries (if you want, you can take a look in lib/accesslib.php and see exactly what those functions are doing internally).